# Is there a way to tell GHC to dump all warnings to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, haskell, command-line, ghc

I've tried the following so far:

```
me@pc:~/code$ ghc file.hs -Wall | tee warnings.log
me@pc:~/code$ ghc file.hs -Wall > warnings.log
```

But `ghc` just prints the warnings like normal and only passes on the non-warning steps.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It prints them to the `stderr`, so you can redirect these with `ghc file.hs -Wall 2>warnings.log`.

Comment: I know it is already resolved, but this should probably be tagged with a bash or linux tag ;)

Comment: If so you could edit the question yourself, but thanks for the notice!

Comment: @schuelermine Users with less than 2,000 reputation cannot edit a different user’s question.

Comment: @FabianSchneider I added them

Comment: @David did not know that, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why it still shows these warnings is because warnings and errors are printed on the standard *error* channel (stderr).

You can thus redirect the errors to a file by redirecting the stderr, with:

```
ghc file.hs -Wall 2> warnings.log
```

Notice the `2` in `2>`. As said before, both the *warnings* and the *exceptions* are printed to this channel.

We can redirect the error stream to `tee` in `bash` with:

```
ghc -Wall file.hs 2> >(tee warnings.log)
```

this features works for `bash`, but as far as I know, this is not defined in the POSIX standard. For `bash` this works, but for `sh`, this seems to fail.